# If the referent is the thing referred to, what is the thing referring?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

This is a very quick question, and the title says it all. For example, we may take the phrase "this tree" (standing, as we are, in front of a tree) to refer to that tree. We call that tree the referent of the phrase "this tree", but what do we call the phrase itself in the context of this narrative of reference?

Thanks.

Comment: Reference. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referent

Comment: Usually, a name has an object as *refernce*; for a sentence, things are a little bit more complicated. A sentence (in the indicative) can refer to a fact, or to a proposition (an abstract objcet) or ... See [Proposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English language, so belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I consider this on topic because it is about the terminology used in a specific branch of philosophy - it can be, as shane pointed out, contrasted with terminology of semiotic theory.

Answer (score 1):

The "reference".

The sign signifies the signified.

The reference refers to the referent.

Comment: Wouldn't the reference be the 'act' of referring? Is that word just overloaded?